# Javascript get only matched text in regex

Tags: javascript

I have string like below

```
BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce
```

I want to convert the string to `13-FEB-31200-ce`

so I tried below code

```
str.match(/(.*)-(?:.*)-(?:.*)-(.*)-(?:.*)-(?:.*)/g)
```

But its returning whole string

Comment: you can see , I even removed 2020

Comment: Well you do not need to use capture groups for things you do not care about. And get rid of the /g flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two capture groups is probably the way to go. Now you have two options to use it. One is match which requires you to put the two pieces together

```js
var str = 'BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce'
var match = str.match(/[^-]+-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-)\d{4}-(.*)/)

// just reference the two groups
console.log(`${match[1]}${match[2]}`)

// or you can remove the match and join the remaining
match.shift()
console.log(match.join(''))
```

Or just string replace which you do the concatenation of the two capture groups in one line.

```js
var str = 'BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce'
var match = str.replace(/[^-]+-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-)\d{4}-(.*)/, '$1$2')
console.log(match)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex doesn't seem to be the most appropriate tool here. Why not use simple `.split`?

```js
let str = 'BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce';
let splits = str.split('-');
let out = [splits[1], splits[2], splits[4], splits[5]].join('-');
console.log(out);
```

If you really want to use regexp,

```js
let str = 'BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce';
let splits = str.match(/[^-]+/g);
let out = [splits[1], splits[2], splits[4], splits[5]].join('-');
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Regex at all if you know exact positions. Using regex is expensive and should be done differently if there is way. (https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

```
const strArr = "BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce".split("-"); // creates array
strArr.splice(0,1); // remove first item
strArr.splice(2,1); // remove 2020
const finalStr = strArr.join("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern doesn't need to be too specific.
Then just keep it simple and only capture what's needed.
Then glue the captured groups together.

```js
let str = 'BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce';

let m = str.match(/^\w+-(\d{1,2}-[A-Z]{3})-\d+-(.*)$/)
let result = m ? m[1]+'-'+m[2] : undefined;

console.log(result);
```

In this regex, `^` is the start of the string and `$` the end of the string.

Comment: The OP also needs to remove the "2020".

Comment: Oh! Really, no year huh. Okay.  Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this by capturing groups with regex:

[image]

```js
const regex = /(\d{2}\-\w{3})(\-\d{4})(\-\d{5}\-\w{2})/

const text = "BANKNIFTY-13-FEB-2020-31200-ce"

const [, a, b, c] = text.match(regex);

console.log(`${a}${c}`)
```

Comment: `-2020` should not be in it